# scraping the website(openpaymentsdata.cms.gov) in r

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am learning to scrape on website "https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/search/physicians?firstname=&lastname=&city=&state=&zip=&country=&specialty="
    data to build a database. 
    Under most cases, I have tried using rvest, XML, Rcurl packages and method html_nodes and XPATH to retrieve the data but however, I could not able scrape the list of Physician name, Specialty, Primary Address from the specified url.

R Code:

```
url <-"https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/search/physicians?firstname=&lastname=&city=&state=&zip=&country=&specialty="
webpage<-read_html(url)
data_html <- html_nodes(webpage ,".a div")
data <-html_text(data_html)

   # I used CSS selector gadget for finding html_nodes

     [Refrence - Screenshot of the CSS selector been used in the image]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKaFM.png

data_html <- html_nodes(webpage ,".a div")
The above code returns that data_html is list of 0
Please guide how to scrape the list of doctors name from the specified url.
```

Comment: Um… _Why?_ Just d/l the data: https://www.cms.gov/OpenPayments/Explore-the-Data/Dataset-Downloads.html

Comment: I want to scrape the data rather downloading that is my assignment

Comment: Issue is that data is loaded dynamically in a container on the website (so if you e.g. in your browser do right click -> page source you won't find the info either). Scraping that is unfortunately more tricky and I won't beable to help you with that ad hoc. One little suggestion: don't use "url" as a varname as it is also a function name `?url()`